# AutoHotkey v2 - Pasting Clipboard within loop doesn't work properly

Tags: loops, automation, autohotkey, clipboard

I've been trying for many days to write a simple code on AutoHotkey v2 that would be the core of a more complex script, but couldn't solve it in any way.

Its purpose:

> Paste the content of the clipboard but pressing [Enter} between each "new line" in the clipboard.

It's like the "Sleep" and "ClipWait" don't actually halt the execution, so the script continues sending the Ctrl+V but with the wrong data in the clipboard. The only way for it to stop the execution thus paste the contents correctly is by using a MsgBox instead of Sleep or ClipWait.

I tried multiple variations of ClipWait and Sleep parameters, and putting them in different parts of the code, also using a "while" loop to check the clipboard content, but nothing worked. Here is my last attempt (in which I tried to use an "if" to stop the execution - didn't work):

```
!^d::
{
    lines := StrSplit(A_Clipboard, "`r`n")
    for index, value in lines
        {
        A_Clipboard := ""
        A_Clipboard := value
        ClipWait
        Sleep 500
        if A_Clipboard := value
            {
            Send "^v"
            if (lines[min(lines.Length,index+1)] != "")
                {
                Send "{Space}"
                }
            if (regexmatch(lines[min(lines.Length,index+1)],"^([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})[.](\s|)"))
                {
                Send "{Enter}"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The items I'm trying to paste are listed items "1. abc 2. def 3. ghi", each separated by a new line. What happens in most of my tests is that it copies the third item three times, or sometimes the second item as well, but never the first one, leading also to the last item to be repeated.

I really hope it's something simple I'm missing and not related to AutoHotkey reliability, and that you guys can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet that might help you achieve this. The code snippet uses the `ClipWait` command to wait for the clipboard to contain data and then uses the `StrSplit()` function to split the clipboard contents into an array of lines. It then loops through each line and pastes it into the active window with an Enter key press between each line. Here is some example code:

```
!^d::
{
    lines := StrSplit(A_Clipboard, "`r`n")
    for index, value in lines
        {
        A_Clipboard := ""
        A_Clipboard := value
        ClipWait
        Sleep 500
        if A_Clipboard := value
            {
            Send "^v"
            if (lines[min(lines.Length,index+1)] != "")
                {
                Send "{Space}"
                }
            if (regexmatch(lines[min(lines.Length,index+1)],"^([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})[.](\s|)"))
                {
                Send "{Enter}"
                }
            }
        }
}
```